# C# List Unions with blank values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Lists containing email addresses.  I am joining them using a list union to get the final email list, however at times, either of the lists could be empty.  What's happening is when a list is empty, it's adding it to the final list as "" after the union, which is causing the email .Send() to crash on the empty email address.  How can I tell the union to ignore empty values?  Here's what I have

```
List<string> _RecordOwnerEmailList = new List<string>();

List<string> _SubmissionEmailList = new List<string>();
List<string> _EmailList = new List<string>();

string _RecordOwnerEmails = String.Empty;
string _SubmissionEmails = String.Empty;

if (dsRecordOwner.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dsRecordOwner.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UpdateEmail"].ToString()))
    _RecordOwnerEmails = dsRecordOwner.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UpdateEmail"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");

if (this.ID > 0)
    _RecordOwnerEmailList = new List<string>(_RecordOwnerEmails.Replace(" ", "").Split(';').ToList());

if (dsEmails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dsEmails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emails"].ToString()))
    _SubmissionEmails = dsEmails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["emails"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");

_SubmissionEmailList = new List<string>(_SubmissionEmails.Replace(" ", "").Split(';').ToList());

_EmailList = _RecordOwnerEmailList.Union(_SubmissionEmailList).ToList();

string[] emails = _EmailList.ToArray();

foreach (string emailAddress in emails)
{ 
    //send email
}
```

Comment: Why cast the list to an array? You can just as easily iterate over the list.

Comment: Please format your code more readably in future. It's very hard to read this at the moment. (I'd also strongly advise shorter lines, more statements with explanatory local variables, and braces in every `if` statement, but that's for your *real* code, not just SO.)

Comment: the code was prewritten to take an array, I just modified the initial array contents with the lists.  Sorry about the formatting, I'll watch that in the future.

Comment: yes, the second list is empty and the union creates an empty value in the array.  the code JaredPar offered worked though (.Where(address => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))).  Thanks!

Comment: union adds an empty string ? I tried doing union of two lists of which one is empty, but it din add an empty string. Please check whether one of the results has an empty string.

Comment: ahhh, I see it now.  Because I initialized _SubmissionEmails = String.Empty, and the dataset that assigned it returned no results, it was creating _SubmissionEmailList to 1 value of String.Empty, which maintained in the Union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter these empty values out with a `Where` clause

```
_EmailList = _RecordOwnerEmailList
  .Union(_SubmissionEmailList)
  .Where(address => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

(_RecordOwnerEmails +";"+_SubmissionEmails).Split(new []{';'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()